# Ionic3 - "data is undefined" #Fetch #Http

Tags: angular, http, ionic2, ionic3

Hey i'm trying to exploit the data that i just fetched from a son file on Ionic 3. 
But nothing appears

Here's my component.html :

```
<h2>Hello</h2>
<h2>Your in "{{data[0].team_name}}"</h2>
<div>Start at: {{data[0].start}}</div>
<div>Stop at: {{data[0].stop}}</div>
```

my component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HttpProvider } from "../../providers/http/http";

export class CheckPage implements OnInit{

data;

ngOnInit():void{
  this.httpProvider.getJsonData()
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(this.data);
        return this.data;
     },
     err =>{
       console.error("Error : "+err);
     },
     () => {
       console.log('getData completed');
       console.log(this.data);
     }
   );
 console.log(this.data);
```

};
 }

my provider :

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HttpProvider {

constructor(public http: Http) {
  console.log('Hello HttpProvider Provider');
}

getJsonData(){
  return this.http.get('../../assets/data/data.json').map(res => res.json());
}
```

}

On my console i have an array with all the data that i just fetched:

```
[…]
0: Object { id: 1, company_name: “Condo”, address: “213 Grove Street”, … }
1: Object { id: 2, company_name: “Ikea”, address: “213 Ikea Street”, … }
2: Object { id: 3, company_name: “McDo”, address: “213 McDo Street”, … }
length: 3
proto: Array []
```

**+** a error message : TypeError: _co.data is undefined

Please what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I think the path to call should be: `http.get('/assets/data/data.json')`. And btw, why are you are you mapping your `JSON` to `.json()`?

Comment: thanks (i just forget to clean my code) but it's not that, i think it's a "timing" problem, my page is loaded before the http call is completed

Comment: You are getting a type error it looks like.  Try changing `data;` to `data :any[];`

Comment: @PhilipBrack i tried it, nothing changed.

Comment: Try putting all of your `data[0]` inside a `<div ngIf=data[0]></div>` to see if it gets rid of error

Comment: @PhilipBrack got a new error => Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:       StaticInjectorError[TemplateRef]:  StaticInjectorError[TemplateRef]: NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef!

Comment: @PhilipBrack never mind :) Yes thanks, i get my 3 [object Object] printed on my page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the view is presented before the object is defined.  The reason you got that specific error is because `data` specifically was undefined and you were accessing it. Update your logic to only present your results when they are available.  Constructs like `ngFor` will take care of that for you.  You can also guard it with `ngIf` like this.

```
<div ngIf=data[0]>
  <h2>Hello</h2>
  <h2>Your in "{{data[0].team_name}}"</h2>
  ...
</div>
```